# How does upvoting comments on Youtube work?

Tags: youtube

Whenever I upvote someone's comment on youtube it seems like it has no effect - likes counter is not increasing (I though it is cached but even if I come back later nothing is changed). Do I need to have some "rep power" for upvoting or comment vote counter is just not 1-to-1 with votes (like 10 votes is required for +1)?

Answer (score 4):

I can duplicate this as well. I'm a logged in user on YouTube and in this video...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdcRtoc0lQU

... I've upvoted this comment posted around 7/28 at 5 PM Pacific

> I just caught the White Queen/Black Queen reference when the poodles were playing chess. Awesome.

... multiple times with no effect. My *reply* on the other hand went through immediately!

I suspect the votes are cached to an extreme degree? I'll check back later and see if it "went through" or not.

edit: **The votes did take effect! It took about 12 hours though.**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe youtube needs some time to count your vote. In the million of users that youtube have, maybe is not so easy to count the votes so fast.

Answer (score 0):

It does fire off a request to youtube.com/comment_voting with the proper parameters. My guess is the server isn't always able to keep up with the incoming requests.

[Youtube request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvvDC.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Could you add to this answer where you got this screenshot from?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube won't show comment upvotes until two (2) upvotes or more have been made.
That means that there is no (1) upvote counter visible, but as soon as two upvotes have been made on a comment, it will show as two upvotes.